# In ANTLR4 lexer how to define negative look behind usecase

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR4 Java I wanted to define a negative look behind use case. For the nested input function or simple function as input based on the argument, it will tokenize and using visitor pattern I have written logic for doing checking grammar.

**LEXER:**

```
lexer grammar MyFunctionsLexer;
NAME: [A-Za-z0-9."[\]'$/\\]+;
DOT: '.';
COMMA: ',';
L_BRACKET: '(';
R_BRACKET: ')';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

**PARSER:**

```
parser grammar MyFunctionsParser;
options { tokenVocab=MyFunctionsLexer; }
functions : function* EOF;
function : NAME '(' (argument (COMMA argument)*)? ')';
argument: (NAME | function );
```

Here based on `COMMA` argument will be tokenized. But I wanted if the `/ followed by ,(Commma)` is there it should not tokenize.

I used `(?<!\/),` as regex in lexer `COMMA` but it is not working.

Sample input:

```
Functions.substring(Functions.concat(String),input[\"/,$csv.test.a\"][\"in\"],Integer,String,Integer,Integer)
```

In the above input `input[\"/,$csv.test.a\"][\"in\"]` is the argument but as `,(Comma)` is there it will split this argument as two parts but as `/ followed ,(Comma)` is there I didn't want to tokenize this into two parts instead it should consider as one.

The error is below :

```
line 1:44 token recognition error at: ','
line 1:53 token recognition error at: ','
com.test.functionvalidate.FunctionInvalidException: line 1:45 at [@6,45:52='input["/',<1>,1:45]: mismatched input 'input["/' expecting {'(?<!\/),', ')'}
    at com.test.functionvalidate.VerboseListener.syntaxError(VerboseListener.java:17)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:544)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportInputMismatch(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:327)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:139)
    at com.functionvalidate.validate.MyFunctionsParser.function(MyFunctionsParser.java:231)
    at com.functionvalidate.validate.MyFunctionsParser.functions(MyFunctionsParser.java:133)
    at com.test.functionvalidate.FunctionValidate.main(FunctionValidate.java:43)
```

Modified lexer for which the above error came:

```
lexer grammar MyFunctionsLexer;
NAME: [A-Za-z0-9."[\]'$/\\]+;
DOT: '.';
COMMA: '(?<!\\/),';
L_BRACKET: '(';
R_BRACKET: ')';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```